# Read configuration data with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, configuration

Is it possible to read asp.net configuration directly using jQuery, without exposing a service or usin the .get function on the client side?

Comment: Hopefully not! It would be a gaping security hole.

Comment: I've never used asp.net, but I doubt you can read server-side configuration from the client without serving it from the server or requesting it from the client. I may well be missing something though ;)

Comment: @Day, no you haven't missed anything :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible because javascript has no access to the server other than using AJAX or simply hardcoding the required values into the DOM. So for example if you needed to access the `foo` value from your `<appSettings>` section you could:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"] }) %>;
    alert(foo.value);
</script>
```

Comment: ok, whats the common approach to read out your app settings then?

Comment: Either pass the required value into the DOM or AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript lives on the client side.

.net lives on the server side.

It is impossible unless you explicitly expose a service for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Server will not serve file with .config extension.